# First Order Logic's Limitations

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In the [wikipedia article for first order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Formalizing_natural_languages) (which is admittedly unreliable but I'm assuming this is consensus anyway), under the "Limitations" section there's a table of statements that first order logic can't formalize. The second one is the following:

> Santa Claus has all the attributes of a sadist

I'm really struggling with this one, why can't you write this as a first order logic sentence? Couldn't you just make 'attributes' objects in the domain of discourse and quantify over them? Something like this:

```
∀x,y,z (Sadist(x) ∧ Attribute(y) ∧ Has(x, y)) ⇒ (Santa(z) ⇒ Has(z, y))
```

Why wouldn't this be a correct formalization of the sentence?

Comment: Maybe it's taking "attribute" to mean "property" and first order logic can't quantify over arbitrary properties -- that is to say, "attribute" is of a different character than "sadist" here; it's a notion in the meta-language, not a first order predicate. I'm not sure, but that's a guess.

Comment: I think the author of the article would say that it is unnatural to have to include attributes as objects in the domain of discourse in single-sorted logic. If we are talking about people, using concepts like "nice", "nasty", "sadistic" our domain of discourse should comprise people and things like "niceness", "nastiness" and "sadism" aren't people. But I think this is subjective and context-dependent: a formulation like yours might be appropriate in artificial intelligence, for example.

Comment: If we let $S=$ the set of all attributes of a sadist, then the statement $\forall x($Santa Claus has $x)$ where $x \in S$ seems legitimate to me. I also have a hard time understanding this one.

Comment: See [Second-order and Higher-order Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#Intr) for examples of **mathematical** facts that we cannot express with FOL.

Comment: Wiki's examploe is quite simplified; it assumes FOL with one sort only of variables, where variables range over individuals in the universe of discourse and properties and relations of individuals are expressed through predicate symbols.